# Android Fragment casting error with second FragmentTransaction.replace() call

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, classcastexception, fragmenttransaction

I have 3 types of fragments all being held in my `fragment_container`in my `classic_menu.xml`for my `MainActivity.java`. I start with fragment A and by pressing a button go to fragment B via a method I have that uses `FragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, B)`. The issue comes when I wish to go to fragment C from B using the same method. I'm getting a casting error using what you see below. *Edit* I get a null pointer by using `findFragmentByTag()` instead of `findFragmentById()`.

Here are the fragments in question:

Fragment A :

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import com.example.R;

    public class MainMenuFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle onSavedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
        }
    }
```

Fragment B :

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import com.example.R;

    public class ClassicMenuFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle onSavedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.classic_menu_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
        }

    }
```

Fragment C :

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import com.example.MainActivity;
    import com.example.R;
    import com.example.widgets.TextViewPlus;

    public class OnePlayerFragment extends Fragment{

    private static TextViewPlus topScore;
    private static TextViewPlus bottomScore;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle onSavedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_player_fragment, container, false);

        topScore = (TextViewPlus) view.findViewById(R.id.topPlayerScore1P);
        bottomScore = (TextViewPlus) view.findViewById(R.id.bottomPlayerScore1P);

        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Changes the text of certain textViewPlus objects based on the given score
     * @param view int value that determines which view to update
     * @param score value to set the text to
     */
    public void setScore(int view, int score){
        if(view == MainActivity.TOP_PLAYER_1P) topScore.setText("" + score);
        else if(view == MainActivity.BOTTOM_PLAYER) bottomScore.setText("" + score);
    }
}
```

The buttons being used:

```
// in main_menu_fragment.xml
<com.example.widgets.ButtonPlus
    android:id="@+id/classicB"
    style="@style/button"
    android:onClick="StartClassicMenu"/>

// in classic_menu_fragment.xml
<com.example.widgets.ButtonPlus
    android:id="@+id/onePlayerB"
    style="@style/button"
    android:onClick="StartGame"/>
```

The `MainActivity.java`:

```
// cut a lot of stuff for brevity
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.fragments.ClassicMenuFragment;
import com.example.fragments.MainMenuFragment;
import com.example.fragments.OnePlayerFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.classic_menu);
    // cut more stuff



    theView = (GameView)findViewById(R.id.theView);         // get reference to the GameView
    // begin the game in Animation mode and pass this MainActivity to the GameView so it can be passed along
    theView.initiateGameThread(GameState.ANIMATION_MODE, this);
    theThread = theView.getThread();                        // get reference to the GameThread
    theGame = theThread.getGameState();                     // get reference to the GameState

    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) return;
        MainMenuFragment mMenu = new MainMenuFragment();
        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, mMenu).commit();
    }
}

public void StartClassicMenu(View v){
    changeToFragment(new ClassicMenuFragment(), "ClassicMenu");
    inFragment = true;
}

public void StartGame(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.onePlayerB:
        theGame.setMode(GameState.ONE_PLAYER_MODE);
        changeToFragment(new OnePlayerFragment(), "OnePlayer");
        Log.d("MainActivity", "StartGame() for 1P mode called");
        break;
    // other cases here but cut out

    theGame.reset();
}

// called from gamestate when views need to be updated
public void setViewScore(int view, int score){
    if(theGame.getMode() == GameState.ONE_PLAYER_MODE){
        Log.d("MainActivity", "setViewScore() for 1P mode called");
        OnePlayerFragment f = (OnePlayerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if(f == null) Log.d("OnePlayerFragment", "null!!!");
        f.setScore(view, score);
    }
    // other cases cut out
}

/**
 * Handles creating and managing a uniform FragmentTransaction for the entire app
 * @param newFragment the new Fragment that will fade in, replacing whichever fragment was in use 
 */
public void changeToFragment(Fragment newFragment, String tag){
    Log.d("MainActivity", "changeToFragment() Called with tag \"" + tag + "\"");
    // Create the standard fade in/out transaction
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    // Replace the old fragment in the Relative Layout view with the new one
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment, tag);
    transaction.commit(); // Commit the transaction
}
```

The `MainActivity`'s respective xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/back_grey">

<com.example.GameView
    android:id="@+id/theView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And now the best part:

```
07-18 16:30:01.999: D/OpenGLRenderer(12335): Enabling debug mode 0
07-18 16:30:02.259: D/GameView(12335): surfaceCreated() Called
07-18 16:30:02.649: I/Timeline(12335): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1f1e5333 time:475861093
07-18 16:30:13.179: D/ViewRootImpl(12335): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
07-18 16:30:13.389: D/MainActivity(12335): changeToFragment() Called with tag "ClassicMenu"
07-18 16:30:14.099: D/ViewRootImpl(12335): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
07-18 16:30:14.169: D/MainActivity(12335): changeToFragment() Called with tag "OnePlayer"
07-18 16:30:14.169: D/MainActivity(12335): StartGame() for 1P mode called
07-18 16:30:14.179: D/MainActivity(12335): setViewScore() for 1P mode called
07-18 16:30:14.219: D/AndroidRuntime(12335): Shutting down VM
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335): Process: com.brownapps.battlepong, PID: 12335
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4222)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4217)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    ... 10 more
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.fragments.ClassicMenuFragment cannot be cast to com.example.fragments.OnePlayerFragment
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at com.example.MainActivity.setViewScore(MainActivity.java:325)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at com.example.GameState$5.run(GameState.java:650)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:5517)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at com.example.GameState.reset(GameState.java:647)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    at com.example.MainActivity.StartGame(MainActivity.java:146)
07-18 16:30:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(12335):    ... 13 more
```

The only other info you may need is that in `theGame`'s `reset()` method it calls `setViewScore()` on the `MainActivity` object passed to it through `theView.initiateGameThread(GameState.ANIMATION_MODE, this);` by using `runOnUiThread()`.

So, my question is then why does the first time I call `changeToFragment()` change the `MainMenuFragment` to a `ClassicMenuFragment`, but screws up the second time when it's supposed to change the `ClassicMenuFragment` to a `OnePlayerFragment`?

Thank you for your time and consideration with this problem of mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ClassCastException` is correct - you can't cast a `ClassicMenuFragment` to a `OnePlayerFragment`. In terms of inheritance, you cannot cast one sibling to another (both of these classes are siblings, with a common parent `Fragment`). An analogy is `Orange` and `Apple` are both children of a class `Fruit`, but you cannot cast an `Orange` to an `Apple` (that doesn't make sense!)

Instead, remove your cast to `OnePlayerFragment` and make use of the `instanceof` keyword, only casting once you are sure which child instance your fragment is:

```
Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
if (f == null) Log.d("Fragment", "null!!!");
if (f instanceof OnePlayerFragment) {
    ((OnePlayerFragment) f).setScore(view, score);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here:

```
 OnePlayerFragment f = (OnePlayerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
```

When you use the `fragment_container` id , it returns the last fragment inflated in your container with the same id, which seems to be the `ClassicMenuFragment` that cannot be cast to `OnePlayerFragment`.

So , if you are sure your fragment is in the stack, change the code above to:

```
 OnePlayerFragment f = (OnePlayerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("OnePlayer");
```

Comment: I had tried this before and get another error (just tried it again to be sure): 
`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.fragments.OnePlayerFragment.setScore(int, int)' on a null object reference`
(thus the `if(f == null) Log.d("OnePlayerFragment", "null!!!");` 
I can see in my log that for some reason `getFragmentByTag` is returning `null` even though I call my `changeToFragment(new OnePlayerFragment(), "OnePlayer")`. Any ideas why this may happen?

Comment: Yes, you're not adding it to the `backStack` in the method `changeToFragment`. You can only retrieve a fragment that way if it is in your backStack

Comment: Still getting a nullpointer error, even with `transaction.addToBackStack(null);` in my `changeToFragment()` method